# NSNumber convert to double issue - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber

I have an array in obj-c with this data and `latitude` and `longitude` is a `NSNumber`

```
[<RequestAddress> 
 [latitude]: 38.63180843974196
 [longitude]: 33.12896232001408
 [addressText]: address Name
 [isStartedPoint]: 1
</RequestAddress>]
```

and I am trying to print the two values and I'm getting it like this

```
if let value = parentNewCarRequestVC.request.address{

    print(value) // value = (
"<RequestAddress> \n   [latitude]: 39.6954240771316\n   [longitude]: 33.10735601860666\n   [addressText]: address Name\n   [isStartedPoint]: 1\n</RequestAddress>"
)

    let number = Double(value[0].latitude)
    print("Result:\(number)") //Result: 6.94109152851164e-310
}
```

while it should be 38.6318

So please where would be my issue?

Comment: What is the value shown for `value[0].latitude`? Did you check this in Playground?

Comment: I have updated my answer which show the content of value. No I didn't check in the playground @RP

Comment: The example array makes no sense and would probably need to be a dictionary, not an array, Research the syntax for defining dictionaries and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If the latitude and longitude are NSNumbers, use the doubleValue property:

```
let number = value[0].latitude.doubleValue
print("Result:\(number)")
```

Comment: When I write it like that I get this error message `Ambiguous reference to member latitude`

Comment: You will need to explain your data structure better. What is RequestAddress? Is it an Object or a Dictionary?

Comment: Is value an array or a single RequestAddress object?

Comment: It is unnecessary to convert the `NSNumber` to a `double`, the print statement will use the `description` method.

Comment: @MrBeardsley it is a RequestAddress object